# executing cd command and ffmpeg in java

Tags: java, jsp, ffmpeg, command, execution

How to run cd command(In linux Ubuntu) and ffmpeg on the changed directory. The following jsp program not working for me.

```
String cmd = "cd "+getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"Files/videos/";
out.println(cmd);

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
    "/bin/sh", "-c", 
    cmd + "&& ffmpeg -i nature.MP4");


Process p = pb.start();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
           new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()) );
String line;
out.println("Meta-data...");
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
  out.println(line);
}
in.close();
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you get errors with that code? At what point and what exception occurs?

Comment: When I execute the above program, no meta-data returning. But when I gone to terminal and apply `cd` command (to the video file location) and then `ffmpeg` command, it works fine.